# Can logging to syslog from inside a container be visible to host's syslog?

Tags: c, docker, ubuntu, stdout, syslog

I have a C application that uses syslog API for logging. This application is further running inside a docker container (FROM ubuntu 20.04)

I am trying to collect the logs from container using the syslog driver.

Did it as documentation says, so running the container with "--log-driver syslog" option.
The documentation also says that logs captured from a container are only the ones from STDOUT and STDERR streams.

STDOUT stream reaches HOST with priority = 6 (INFO),
STDERR stream reaches HOST with priority = 3 (ERROR obviously)

I need a method to see in the hosts syslog the logs from container exactly in the same way I would see them from application running natively. (with different priorities)

Comment: I don't get your question.. you need to see the logs from the container "exactly the same" but "with different priorities", which is it now and why would you need different priorities? Logs have a specific priority for a  reason.

Also, could you provide some information on what you've tried to solve your problem?

Comment: By exactly the same (with different priorities) I mean that I want to get the logs from container with full range of priorities. Using syslog driver as documentation says I can only capture STDOUT, which is priority 6 and STDERR which is priority 3. I need all range of priorities.

Comment: I would love to solve similar case. The issue is, Linux containers have nothing to do with regard to syslog. There is nothing to process calls to syslog() unless you run it yourself. As far as I can tell, you can run a syslog daemon in the background next to the main process in the same container (you can achieve that with custom entrypoint). Or you can run syslog daemon in other container, if your program can connect to remote syslog server, and connect the two containers via some IPC (like IP or shared Unix-domain sockets). Neither seems good and I hope I am missing something…

Comment: Solved, or at least my need is now satisfied. Instead of getting logs with integrated docker syslog driver, I just mapped /dev/log of the host to the container by adding "-v /dev/log:/dev/log" flag.